# Non-US resident: tax comparison for ETF domicle in US vs Ireland

Tags: taxes, etf, non-resident

I am a non-US resident. I am evaluating taxation on US-domiciled ETF vs Ireland-domiciled ETF.

#### Assumptions

- The country of the investor's residence has tax treaty with the US (the withholding tax in the US is 15%).
- The local tax in the country of the investor's residence tax is 19%.
- The country of the investor's residence allows deduction of the withholding tax (i.e. the investor pays only the delta between the withheld tax and the local tax).

#### 1. US-domiciled ETF distributing dividends.

- Tax rate on dividends paid from companies to the ETF is 0%.
- Withholding tax rate on dividends paid by ETF to the investor is 15%.
- Local tax rate on dividends received by the investor is 4%.

**Total: 19%**

#### 2. IE-domiciled ETF distributing dividends.

- Withholding tax rate on dividends paid from companies to the ETF is 15%.
- Withholding tax rate on dividends paid by ETF to the investor is 0%.
- Local tax rate on dividends received by the investor is 19%.

**Total: 31.15%**

#### 3. US-domiciled ETF accumulating dividends.

Not applicable: US-companies must pay dividends at least once a year to non-US residents.

#### 4. IE-domiciled ETF accumulating dividends.

- Withholding tax rate on dividends paid from companies to the ETF is 15%.
- Withholding tax rate on dividends paid by ETF to the investor is 0% (no dividends).
- Immediate local tax rate on dividends received by the investor is 0% (no dividends).
- Local tax rate on realized gains after sale is 19% (no tax on unrealized gains).

**Total: less or equal to 31.15%** depending on the investment period

#### Questions

1. Is there anything wrong in the above calculations?
2. How to compare Option 4 against Options 1 and 2, assuming 10 years as an exemplary investment period?
3. In what conditions, Option 4 becomes more optimal compared to Option 1?

**Update:** the country of the investor's residence doesn't have any Estate or Gift Treaty with the US, but let's ignore the Estate tax for simplicity.

Comment: Are you implying that 19% local tax means 19% Dividend Tax and 19% Capital Gains Tax?

Comment: @base64, yes, the tax rate is the same.

Comment: @base64, added information to the question that there is no tax on unrealized gains.

Comment: Yes I assumed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Answer**

1. Nothing wrong if you only consider the total dividend tax while ignoring that 4% less immediate tax each year in Option 4 provides additional chance for compounding capital gains.
2. One suggest way is to draw up spreadsheet showing year-by-year effect such as below.
3. When the dividends from Option 4 are not subject to any local tax (except capital gains on the gains of reinvested dividend), or when you consider ... the up to 40% US Estate Tax (Note: There is 1.5% overall [chance of death](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html) between Age 20 and 30). The forecasted dividend yield and capital gains do not affect the winner it seems.

Assumptions:

- $100 Lump Sum investment for 10 years
- 2% Gross Dividend Yield each year
- 8% Capital Gains each year
- Reinvested Dividend (including manually)
- For Option 4, although dividend not distributed to the individual, the Net Asset Value / Price of ETF increased. Local capital gains tax of 19% applies as if the Dividends are aquired at $0 cost basis.

Here you can see that Option 1 is **1.5% better** than Option 4 over 10 years.

[image: A]

**Partial Answer**

If your country of residence (not citizenship) does not have [Estate or Gift Tax Treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/estate-gift-tax-treaties-international) with the United States, regardless of the Income Tax Treaty status (except Canada), the US-domiciled ETFs (including Treasury Bonds ETFs after 2011) are subject to up to 40% US Estate Tax if held in an individual account.

IE-domiciled ETFs do not have US Estate Tax, not because of Income / Estate Tax Treaty, but because IE-domiciled ETFs are not "US Situs" assets. The companies inside the IE-domiciled ETFs are "US Situs" but the owner (i.e. the ETF itself) does not "die", hence there is no US Estate Tax triggered.

Comment: I have edited. The topic of estate tax depends on how much you care between 0% Estate Tax and up to 40% Estate Tax. It's subjective.

Comment: "IE-domiciled ETF does pay the Estate tax anyway" is totally untrue. US Estate Tax is applied to "US Situs Asset" (Assets situated in the US, including US common stocks) upon a death of an owner who is a Natural Person. An IE-domiciled ETF is neither US Situs Asset, not did the ETF "die".

Comment: Yes I purely mean US Estate Tax. I never knew your local estate tax rate nor whether there is foreign estate tax relief/credit.

Comment: I updated the question. You are right that this information may be relevant in scope of the question, but I skip it for simplicity.

Comment: @Peggy Edited again.